# 'It looks like you don't have permissions' message Saving docs in library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, spreadsheet

We moved a SharePoint 2010 site to a new server and new domain. All users were migrated over to the new domain. One user, who is a member of two different domain groups, has contribute access set for both groups in a document library in the site. They can get to the library and they can open a spreadsheet but when they go to save it the message "It looks like you don't have permissions to do this. You could try contacting the document owner or your help desk to get permissions". They are the document owner though. Any ideas what the issue might be?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a file issue not a SharePoint issue. The easiest thing to do would probably be a simple cut and paste of the file contents to a new file and the upload the new version. In my limited opinion it sounds like some of the document ownership metadata was corrupted during your move. Is this the only file that is doing this?

Comment: I logged into SharePoint as the user who is receiving this issue and had no issues saving the document. If the document ownership metadata was corrupted wouldn't I be experiencing the same issue on my computer?

Answer (score 0):

I met with the client and got them to share their screen. There was a message along the top of the spreadsheet that said that there was an error uploading because the file was checked out to me. I had been testing with my account and hers and had no issues saving the sheet with Office 2010 and 2016 (which is what they have).

I checked the file back in, got her to close the file, refresh and then reopen. Same thing.

I got them to download the file to their desktop, make a change and save it. I then got them to upload it and open it. The change wasn't there and it still said that it was checked out to me.

I then got them to delete the file from SP and re-upload the one from her desktop. Same thing happened: change wasn't there and it was still saying it was checked out to me.

I then got her to punt the file from SP once again, rename the file on her desktop and upload it. She was able to open, it see her change, the message that is was checked out to me was gone and she was able to save her changes with no issues.

***shrug***